# What does "phantom central" mean?

Tags: nouns, adjective-order, postpositive-adjectives

I would understand a *central phantom*. The word-order puzzles me.  Does *phantom central* have a specific meaning? Is *central* a postpositive adjective there? Thanks in advance :).

> And now a madcap humour came upon me. It was plain Bellairs had been communicating with his principal; I knew the number, if not the name. Should I ring up at once? It was more than likely he would return in person to the telephone. Why should not I dash(vocally) into the presence of this mysterious person, and have some fun for my money? I pressed the bell.
> "Central," said I, "connect again 2241 and 584 B."
> A **phantom central** repeated the number; there was a pause, and then "Two two four one," came in a tiny voice into my ear - a voice with the English sing-song - the voice plainly of a gentleman.

(*The Wrecker* by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, chapter x)

There is another thing that puzzles me. The text says there is the telephone number **584 B**. Were there letter-dials in addition to the number-dial in America in former times?

[The Wrecker - Robert Louis Stevenson](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_10)

Comment: Your additional question is not about the English language, but I'll address it here.  Rotary dials had three numbers assigned to each number on the dial.  So, 584 B would be the equivalent of 584-2 (since ABC were assigned to the number 2).  But this is inconsequential here, because the narrator is speaking to an operator, not dialing.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: The phantom is the imaginary inner voice of the speaker, repeating the number for no reason other than the drama. He is pretending.

Comment: @Juhasz : I think that "554B" addresses a party line where the number 554 corresponds to the line (shared by multiple users) and the "B" corresponds to a specific ring tone to be set by the operator to inform subscribers who is(are) the target of the call.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I disagree - don't see any indication that this doesn't refer to a real person at central actually repeating the number out loud. The sentence as a whole is describing things that physically occur - central repeats the number, there's a pause, and then someone answers. There's nothing to suggest that the first part of the sentence is imagined rather than actually happening. Phantom doesn't mean "imaginary".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, "central" refers to a telephone switchboard or something like it, essentially a central location where communications are routed from. "Phantom" is used as an adjective to indicate that the person at "central" has phantom-like qualities, alluding to the fact that they are unseen and that contact with them is ephemeral - it's an interesting way of describing brief contact with a disembodied voice.

Comment: "Accepted" as well. Why ever not can't I accept both the replies - it puzzles me?!?

Comment: Yes. This usage still exists in French, where _un central téléphonique_ is what Anglos called a 'telephone exchange' in the days of analogue phones.  _Un central_ can also be an electric power station.

Answer (score 1):

This is a probably outdated use of the word *central*.

> **central** noun
>
> 1 : a telephone exchange or operator

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/central)

The cited text is from 1892, at which time phone calls had to be facilitated by human operators.  The narrator wishes to place a phone call and to do so, he must ask a switchboard operator, in this case, at the *central* office, to manually connect his line (2241) to another line (584 B).

To do so, he addresses a request, "connect again 2241 and 584 B," to the switchboard operator, whom he's referring to by the name of their office, "Central."

So, this grammatically very standard.  The adjective *phantom* modifies the noun *central*.  What's the meaning of a phantom switchboard operator?  That's left to your interpretation.